# Cannot convert this php array into xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp v2.5. I would like to convert an array into xml. The array looks like this;

```
$Items = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Item' => array(
            'id' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Item' => array(
            'id' => '4'
        )
    )
)
```

To convert this array to xml, the following php code was run;

```
$xmlObject = Xml::fromArray(array('response' => $Items ));
echo $xmlObject->asXML();
```

Unfortunately, the following error was encountered;

```
Warning (2): SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document [CORE\Cake\Utility\Xml.php, line 221]
```

How can this array be converted into xml in php or cakephp (using cake's built-in functions)?

EDIT: I found the problem but still not have the solution. The output of `array('response' => $Items)` returns a `maximum depth reached` message. Anyone can advise?

Answer (score 1):

Try it to do manually

```
//just initialize this array to a xml tags data.
//<id></id> so intialize it with id
// E.g. $tags_array = ('id');
$tags_array = $Row1[0]; //here $Row1[0] is my tags array.


foreach($tags_array as $tags)
{
    // Doing this thing because space xml tags will create a problem.
     $tags1     = str_replace(" ","_",$tags_array);
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');   
$output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
$output .= "<root>"; 

$total_tags=count($tags);

for($i=0; $i <= count($arr); $i++)
{   
  for($tag=0;$tag < $total_tags; $tag++)
   {
     $output .= '<'.$tags[$tag].'>';
     $output .= $arr[$i][$tag];
     $output .= '</'.$tags[$tag].'>';
   }
}
$output .= "</root>";

echo $output;
```

Comment: I am afraid this is a too tedious way to create web services. But thanks. Will use this method as last resort. Upvoted.

Comment: it is not so tadious. will work. i used it in my many big websites with their huge data.if need any help on this will availabel always. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlObject = Xml::fromArray('response' => $Items );
 echo $xmlObject->asXML();
```

Doing like this worked for me.... Try i